# When using nsupdate to update both A and PTR records, why do I get "update failed: update RR is outside zone (NOTZONE)"?

Tags: bind

When using the following input to nsupdate to assign both an A record and a PTR record at the same time:

```
server dns01.example.com
update delete pup01.example.com. A
update add pup01.example.com. 300 A 172.29.207.209
update delete 209.207.29.172.in-addr.arpa. PTR
update add 209.207.29.172.in-addr.arpa. 300 PTR pup01.example.com.
send
```

We get the following error returned by bind9:

```
Sep 23 14:26:12 dns01 named[1070]: client 172.29.207.209#25781/key example.com: view example.com-default: updating zone 'example.com/IN': update failed: update RR is outside zone (NOTZONE)
```

What does the error mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on a bug report from 2004 at https://mail-index.netbsd.org/current-users/2004/06/19/0002.html, the solution is as follows:

A blank line needs to be introduced between the setting of the A record and the setting of the PTR record, like this:

```
server dns01.example.com
update delete pup01.example.com. A
update add pup01.example.com. 300 A 172.29.207.209
[blank line goes here]
update delete 209.207.29.172.in-addr.arpa. PTR
update add 209.207.29.172.in-addr.arpa. 300 PTR pup01.example.com.
send
```

This results in the following in the log:

```
Sep 23 14:40:12 dns01 named[1070]: client 172.29.207.209#36127/key example.com: view example.com-default: updating zone 'example.com/IN': deleting rrset at 'pup01.example.com' A
Sep 23 14:40:12 dns01 named[1070]: client 172.29.207.209#36127/key example.com: view example.com-default: updating zone 'example.com/IN': adding an RR at 'pup01.example.com' A
Sep 23 14:40:12 dns01 named[1070]: client 172.29.207.209#36127/key example.com: view example.com-default: updating zone '29.172.in-addr.arpa/IN': deleting rrset at '209.207.29.172.in-addr.arpa' PTR
Sep 23 14:40:12 dns01 named[1070]: client 172.29.207.209#36127/key example.com: view example.com-default: updating zone '29.172.in-addr.arpa/IN': adding an RR at '209.207.29.172.in-addr.arpa' PTR
```

Hopefully this saves someone some time.

Comment: A blank line is equivalent to `send` so this is really just sending two separate requests.